# What is the status of the TV and movie rights to ASOIAF given the end of the original HBO series?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Now, I'm not a *Game of Thrones* fan, but a number of facts are floating around the internet which I will outline below as I understand them.   (I could dig up more citations, and I would appreciate if someone else did, but I personally can't invest the time right now for facts which don't seem to be in dispute and aren't really critical to the question.)

- George R.R. Martin intends the ASOIAF series to be seven novels long
- Five have been completed, two have been pending for eight years, with no end in sight
- He recently made a [comment](https://uproxx.com/hitfix/george-rr-martin-winds-of-winter-imprison-worldcon/) implying that *The Winds of Winter* should be complete by July 2020.
- Due to the long delay in writing the final books, the *Game of Thrones* TV series passed the novels.
- Martin provided outlines to the writers of the TV series (David Benioff) and (D.B.Weiss)
- It's the general consensus that D&D lost interest in the series, and agreed to do fewer and shorter seasons than HBO (and the fan base) wanted
- The final 8th season of *GoT* was widely panned for its writing, for being rushed, nonsensical and undoing or destroying various previous plot and character deployment
- As a result of this there is [a petition](https://www.change.org/p/hbo-remake-game-of-thrones-season-8-with-competent-writers) to remake the final season which has garnered 1.5 million signatures

Now, it is clearly unlikely that HBO will remake anything in the short term (though there are spin offs).   However, Hollywood tends to find a way to make whatever money there is to be made.   And there is clearly a lot of money to make.   This together with the fact that the final release of the novels, *The Winds of Winter* and *A Dream of Spring* in two or five or ten years would seem to provide a context and opportunity to make definitive TV/movie content covering this material.

**What is the status of any rights to make or remake material from ASOIAF, in particular covering the yet-to-be-released novels?**

Links: [Martin's comments](http://georgerrmartin.com/notablog/2019/05/20/an-ending/) after the airing of the last episode of GoT.

Comment: What are the rights to a show **that's only just been aired?** I would imagine that they're totally tied to the production company for the next few decades, along with any additional books that he writes in the same fictional universe.

Comment: @Valorum This question seems to be about rights to the as-yet-unreleased **book** material, which may be significantly different from the existing show. (Edit: OK, you edited your comment, but the point is, are there any sources to document that last claim?)

Comment: @Valorum, and rather than "imagining", it is the opportunity to answer.

Comment: The rights to *all unreleased (and potentially quite different) material* that GRRM might write in the series? If you've got a source for that, then you can answer this. Not saying you're wrong, but not everyone is showbiz-savvy enough to see this as so "obvious" as it seems to you.

Comment: This isn't a fantasy question but something for https://law.stackexchange.com/ or whatever.

Answer (score 10):

In 2007, HBO acquired the film and TV rights to GRRM's A Song of Ice and Fire series of books. It would appear (bearing in mind that these deals are subject to intense commercial confidentiality) that this includes all future works within the same fictional universe, noting that a) the options were exercised when only *four* of the books had been written and published and b) that 'option clauses' do typically cover any and all writings [within the same book series or setting](https://twitter.com/SusanSpann/status/832015492021825536).

> Home Box Office has acquired an option on the **television and film
> rights to my fantasy series, A Song of Ice and Fire,** in hopes of
> bringing the story to television as an original, ongoing HBO series.
> We have been working out the details for months, but the deal is
> finally done and the pieces are in place, so it’s official.
>
> <sub><sup>[HBO OPTIONS ICE & FIRE - JANUARY 18, 2007](http://www.georgerrmartin.com/hbo-options-ice-fire/)</sup></sub>

There's no good indication when the optioned rights to any new works would lapse and typically this includes the right to also remake or reboot a series (from earlier works) if the studio so desire, possibly [subject to agreement with the author](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/199250/20774).

Comment: Some more context - https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/game-thrones-sequel-is-not-an-option-hbo-series-finale-1212749?fbclid=IwAR2WadjMvDuyufPJ0K4Nr4WUhsiyZ1W3E_QZw0iWSfQ11L7PYXEHIB_nI_g

Comment: I remember reading an article that mentioned that only A Song of Ice and Fire was purchased, and that any 'spin-offs' would be difficult to host on other networks because they would need to buy the rights to the characters from HBO, and it would be easier if HBO decided to purchase the rights to additional stories and produce the seasons themselves.  I'll update my answer if I can track down that article

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Valorum's great answer, I did see the following article: [A 'Game of Thrones' Sequel Is Not an Option for HBO's Top Executive](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/game-thrones-sequel-is-not-an-option-hbo-series-finale-1212749)

> **The three successor shows are all prequels. In the finale, Arya goes on to explore what's west of Westeros. Have you considered exploring sequels? Specifically, Arya Stark as she travels west of Westeros?**
>
> Nope, nope, nope. No. Part of it is, I do want this show — this Game
>   of Thrones, Dan and David's show — to be its own thing. I don't want
>   to take characters from this world that they did beautifully and put
>   them off into another world with someone else creating it. I want to
>   let it be the artistic piece they've got. That's one of the reasons
>   why I'm not trying to do the same show over. George has a massive,
>   massive world; there are so many ways in. That's why we're trying to
>   do things that feel distinct — and to not try and redo the same show.
>   That's probably one of the reasons why, right now, a sequel or picking
>   up any of the other characters doesn't make sense for us.

Comment: _"We're not doing a sequel... for now"_ sounds about right

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question asked (about the rights), just the overt intention. They could, for example, change their minds